# Error Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index 'IX_AP_Payables_PayableNo'. But there is no such column name like that?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, I know this title already has many questions in StackOverflow but this is a little different here, please hear me till the end.

First, take a look at my error :

> Cannot insert a duplicate key row in object 'dbo.FI_ARAP' with unique index 'IX_AP_Payables_PayableNo'.

in the error above it said that Columns names `PayableNo` can't duplicate, but to surprise me is, there is no such column name `PayableNo` in all of our database Table, Procedure or even Function.

I have search using this code :

```
SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
          FROM syscolumns 
          WHERE name like '%PayableNo%' )
```

or using this

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%PayableNo%' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

And all of them resulting resulting none, nothing found in all table or procedure or even function. But i got that error saying i can't duplicate key on non existing column ?

Why is this happening?

The insert statement is pretty long but if you want to know, here it is :

```
INSERT INTO P_BS.dbo.FI_ARAP WITH (ROWLOCK) (Class,
                                             VoucherNo,
                                             VoucherCounter,
                                             VoucherDate,
                                             IsAR,
                                             IncomeOrExpense,
                                             AssociateID,
                                             AssociateName,
                                             CurrencyID,
                                             ExchangeRate,
                                             PaymentMethod,
                                             VoucherType,
                                             RecordedGuestID,
                                             IsFODeposit,
                                             ExpenseOrRevenueTypeID,
                                             ReservationID,
                                             CutFare,
                                             DontPostToGL,
                                             BankAccountID,
                                             CheckNo,
                                             CheckDueDate,
                                             ClearingID,
                                             BankName,
                                             CardHolderName,
                                             AccountNo,
                                             AmountPaid,
                                             Remarks,
                                             InternalRemarks,
                                             ExcludeInARAP,
                                             CollectorID,
                                             CardTypeID,
                                             CardTerminalID,
                                             [External],
                                             AccountOwner,
                                             HMSDate,
                                             HMSShiftID,
                                             POSOID,
                                             CreatedBy,
                                             CreateDate,
                                             LastModBy,
                                             LastMod,
                                             IncomingTransferVerified,
                                             AutoGenerated,
                                             GoldAdjustmentID,
                                             Confidential,
                                             EmployeeAdvance,
                                             Transferred,
                                             DeductedPPh,
                                             ExSourceID,
                                             ExSource,
                                             WriteOffDepartment,
                                             AccountIndex,
                                             BIAssetID,
                                             BIDriverID,
                                             IsPanjarUJ,
                                             BankCharges,
                                             BankChargesAccountID,
                                             BankChargesDepartment,
                                             PIN,
                                             SourceCashRefundID,
                                             PPhTypeID,
                                             EBankingMetadata,
                                             FPNo,
                                             BQID,
                                             ProjectID,
                                             Pending,
                                             DeliveryOrderID,
                                             KCPDeliveryOrderID,
                                             FFBContractID,
                                             SourceVoucherID,
                                             IncentiveDetailID,
                                             ExternalRef,
                                             OtherOwnerCheck,
                                             IsSODeposit,
                                             TransferDate,
                                             Jaminan,
                                             WriteOffAccountID,
                                             PVTax,
                                             PVAmountTax,
                                             ForexGainLossDepartment,
                                             ForexGainLossAccountID,
                                             IsPriviledge,
                                             PriviledgeCardNumber,
                                             PPhFormula,
                                             CashFlowID,
                                             PVSalesPersonID,
                                             PalmContractID,
                                             ExpMeterai,
                                             CashRate,
                                             PPhLocal,
                                             IsAnonym,
                                             AnonymName,
                                             RequireCheck,
                                             EDUHideDiscount,
                                             EDUDiscReason,
                                             BAccountType,
                                             PPh23ID,
                                             SettlementDescription,
                                             AdvanceAccountID,
                                             EDUReportDate,
                                             DedOtobon,
                                             City,
                                             Branch,
                                             Country,
                                             IBANCode,
                                             SwiftCode,
                                             SortCode,
                                             PendingCashID,
                                             PendingCashAmount,
                                             ChargeAmount,
                                             BranchCode,
                                             ABACode,
                                             CorrBank,
                                             CorrSwiftCode,
                                             AllowOverBudget,
                                             POTerm)
VALUES (@Class,
        @VoucherNo,
        @VoucherCounter,
        @VoucherDate,
        @IsAR,
        @IncomeOrExpense,
        @AssociateID,
        @AssociateName,
        @CurrencyID,
        @ExchangeRate,
        @PaymentMethod,
        @VoucherType,
        @RecordedGuestID,
        @IsFODeposit,
        @ExpenseOrRevenueTypeID,
        @ReservationID,
        @CutFare,
        @DontPostToGL,
        @BankAccountID,
        @CheckNo,
        @CheckDueDate,
        0,
        @BankName,
        @CardHolderName,
        @AccountNo,
        @AmountPaid,
        @Remarks,
        @InternalRemarks,
        @ExcludeInARAP,
        @CollectorID,
        @CardTypeID,
        @CardTerminalID,
        @External,
        @AccountOwner,
        @HMSDate,
        @HMSShiftID,
        @POSOID,
        @LoginName,
        GETDATE(),
        @LoginName,
        GETDATE(),
        0,
        @AutoGenerated,
        @GoldAdjustmentID,
        @Confidential,
        @EmployeeAdvance,
        1,
        @DeductedPPh,
        @ExSourceID,
        @ExSource,
        @WriteOffDepartment,
        @AccountIndex,
        @BIAssetID,
        @BIDriverID,
        @IsPanjarUJ,
        @BankCharges,
        @BankChargesAccountID,
        @BankChargesDepartment,
        @PIN,
        @SourceCashRefundID,
        @PPhTypeID,
        @EBankingMetadata,
        @FPNo,
        @BQID,
        @ProjectID,
        @Pending,
        @DeliveryOrderID,
        @KCPDeliveryOrderID,
        @FFBContractID,
        @SourceVoucherID,
        @IncentiveDetailID,
        @ExternalRef,
        @OtherOwnerCheck,
        @IsSODeposit,
        @TransferDate,
        @Jaminan,
        @WriteOffAccountID,
        @PVTax,
        @PVAmountTax,
        @ForexGainLossDepartment,
        @ForexGainLossAccountID,
        @IsPriviledge,
        @PriviledgeCardNumber,
        @PPhFormula,
        @CashFlowID,
        @PVSalesPersonID,
        @PalmContractID,
        @ExpMeterai,
        @CashRate,
        @PPhLocal,
        @IsAnonym,
        @AnonymName,
        0,
        @EDUHideDiscount,
        @EDUDiscReason,
        @BAccountType,
        @PPh23ID,
        @SettlementDescription,
        @AdvanceAccountID,
        @EDUReportDate,
        @DedOtobon,
        @City,
        @Branch,
        @Country,
        @IBANCode,
        @SwiftCode,
        @SortCode,
        @PendingCashID,
        @PendingCashAmount,
        @ChargeAmount,
        @BranchCode,
        @ABACode,
        @CorrBank,
        @CorrSwiftCode,
        @AllowOverBudget,
        @POTerm);
```

Comment: `IX_AP_Payables_PayableNo` is just the name of the unique index. Perhaps it is not a very descriptive name, if it doesn't refer to existing objects, but it is still just a name. You should look at its definition to find out which column has the the unique constraint.

Comment: Considering that you ave no column with `Payable` in the name, I would suggest it's not a descriptive name.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, hello, tried your clue of the unique index and google for how to search it, I got where the source of definition now, thanks. 

but i still a beginner at how this unique index works, when I take a look inside the definition it has 3 columns like this 

        `[IsAR] ASC`,
 `[Class] ASC`,
 `[VoucherNo] ASC`

what is that mean ? is that tell me 3 of those column must not be duplicated ?

Comment: It means the combination of those columns have to be unique.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, thank you, i now have clear my problem from your comment. Unfortunately I can't accept a comment as answer in StackOverflow, do you want to create an answer so i can accept yours ?

Comment: Stop adding table or query hints without reason. That is a bad habit to develop.

Comment: @SMor, I know what you mean, I'm not the one develop this, this is just our ex-employee create and I just inherited from him. unfortunately, his software is already used for our company as ERP so i can't make a big change for this thing

Answer (score 0):

The name doesn't say which columns are used in the index. You can check with the following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'IX_AP_Payables_PayableNo'
```

Using the above query you should find at least one record for table `FI_ARAP` and the columns included in the `UNIQUE` index. All these columns together have to be unique in combination.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering but i have tried your query but unfortunately still no result found